# storing value in reverse?

Tags: c, pointers

I wrote the function to concatenate two strings using pointers. Like strcat(s,t), so at the end of s, t will be added..

```
   int main ()
{
  char b[] = "Hello";
  char b1[] = "world";
  string_cat(b,b1);
  printf("Concatenated string is %s\n",b);
  return 0;
}
int string_cat(char *s, char *d)
{
  while(*++s != '\0')
    ;
  *s++ = ' ';
  while((*s++ = *d++)!='\0');  // Concatenation
  printf("S is %c\n",s[-2]);   // Just to see the values
}
```

Concatenation works fine, but when I want to see the way elements are stored, all the elements are stored in negative direction, what I mean is s[-2] equals to 'd', s[-3] equals 'l' .. Is this the way they are stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up `b` is too small to hold the concatenated string. It has only enough space to hold `Hello\0` so what you are doing is undefined. Second, look at this line:

```
while((*s++ = *d++)!='\0');
        ^^^
```

You're advancing `s` because you're incrementing it. Each time you increment it you should imagine it points one element forward. When you get to the end, `s` isn't what it started out to be. So `s[-2]` is actually farther down the line compared to the original `s` (`b` in your case).

---

#### EDIT

> so, how to declare it, so that it dynamically adjusts to new size?

Making it adjust to the right size it tough, if possible. What you can do:

- Declare it like so: `char b[LENGTH] = "Hello"`;
- Pass another parameter to `string_cat` specifying the size

After multiple iterations you will eventually end up with something like `strncpy` / `memcpy`.

Comment: so, how to declare it, so that it dynamically adjusts to new size?

Answer (score 2):

Its not stored in negative direction but rather, because you are incrementing the pointer (`*s++` in the while loop `while((*s++ = *d++)!='\0');`)while concatenating , so at the end `s` points to the end of the string.
You may want to save a copy of the pointer to ensure that you don't loose the beginning of the string (if you need) inside `string_cat`

Your code has other potential problems which would lead to stack buffer overrun.

```
char b[] = "Hello";
```

is a fixed size buffer. Concatenating `b1` with `b` would eventually lead to buffer overrun causing a UB and might eventually crash.